# Create factory for require node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, module, require

I want to create factory/or similar approach  based on the required OS windows/linux
for example if linux use

```
var isLinux = /^linux/.test(process.platform);
var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);

if(isLinux){
var spawn = require('child-process');
}{
elseif(isWin)

var spawn = require('cross-spawn')
}
module.export = spawn;
```

I know that the cross-spawn is also for windows...
my question is there a nicer way to write it in node (ver4.4) instead of just else if

Comment: I see a syntax error in `}{
elseif(isWin)`

Comment: Why not just always use `cross-spawn`?

Comment: @Tushar - i'll fix :) this is just for the example...

Comment: @BenFortune - I want to avoid this run in linux I want to still run the native spawn ...

Comment: @BenFortune - I know that this is not that clear why (since the cross-spawn use some fork for asking about OS...) :)  But I still need to use it like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch(process.platform){
  case 'windows': 
    // code
    break;
  case 'linux':
    // code
    break;
  default:
    return new Error('give us a real OS pls')
}
```

or

```
process.platform === 'windows' ? 
  //code windows : 
  //code linux
```

Here's some more food for thought. [Alternatives](https://toddmotto.com/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals/) to switch statements.